# Setting up a Q&A site with WP plugin or WP theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to set up a Q&A site using WP. I found two possible solutions. One is a plugin (http://www.designwall.com/wordpress/plugins/dw-question-answer/) and another is a theme (http://themeforest.net/item/qanda-wp-questions-and-answers/4524028?WT.ac=search_item&WT.oss_phrase=question&WT.oss_rank=1&WT.z_author=feeleep).

I will need to localize the interface and do some UI changes to fit with the targeted community. I'm not familiar with WP. Can you please advise, which one is a better choice in term of customization and maintenance? Thanks.

Comment: I'm certain that there will be disagreement about this but my recommendation would be  **Question2Answer** Wordpress integration - http://www.question2answer.org/wordpress.php.

Comment: DesignWall is free and updated recently. Qanda hasn't been updated in a while. SabaiDiscuss, cited on [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones) seem nice. There's another one mentioned there, but I don't like the company.